# Web form for marketers is not supporting multiple language

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using Sitecore WFFM to render a form. it is working fine in default language but in the case of multiple languages like if I am changing language then form is not rendering. So my question is that is WFFM support in multiple language condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible in case of WFFM, you only need to create new language version of your form and then fill field name in your required language it will start showing in current language.

Please don't forget to change language in QueryString :)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that save actions are NOT multi-lingual so please be aware, in the case of say a contact us for different countries.